# Parsing BBCode with normal text

Tags: c#, regex

I had created a `Regular Expression` to parse `BBCode`. The `Regular Expression` checking each `BBCode` tag and move it to an `Matching`/`Group`.

Here is the `Regular Expression` (**Live-Example**: https://regex101.com/r/p3LtrK/3):

```regex
\[(\w+)(?:[= ]([^\]]+))?]((?:.|[\r\n])*?)\[\/\1]
```

I'm a bit over the top because I have already tried all kinds of possibilities to add a new `Matching`/`Group`. I want to add to the `Regular Expression` all other strings/text as an `Matching`/`Group`.

I had try to following changes:

- Try with `OR`: `($NewRegex|$BBCodeRegex)`
- Try with `Grouping` other strings/texts up to maximum of starting BBCode `[`: `(^[\[]+)`

The problem is, i want the grouping exactly on the input. Currently i get some sample output:

```
#0 [tag]<content>[/tag]
#1 [tag]<content>[/tag]
#2 [tag]<content>[/tag]
#3 [tag]<content>[/tag]
```

And that is, what i needed:

```
#0 [tag]<content>[/tag]
#1 <text>
#1 [tag]<content>[/tag]
#2 <text>
#3 [tag]<content>[/tag]
#4 [tag]<content>[/tag]
#5 <text>
#6 [tag]<content>[/tag]
```

Are you have some solutions?

Comment: Why not split it with your regex? `preg_split('~\[(\w+)(?:[= ][^\]]+)?].*?\[/\1]~s', $s)`? You will get all text other than your pattern matches.

Comment: i dont use PHP, i dont know its available on C#

Comment: Do you realize you shared a PHP/PCRE demo? It is natural I assumed you are  using PHP. Next time remember to add appropriate language tag. Regex101 does not support .NET syntax and whatever you test there does not have to work in C# or any other .NET language.

Comment: RegularExpression is RegularExpression. Its not relevant, which language are you using, Regex is standardconform. And your informations are bad, these works on C# to:

```c#
Regex regex = new Regex("\\[(\\w+)(?:[= ]([^\\]]+))?]((?:.|[\r\n])*?)\\[/\\1]");
            MatchCollection results = regex.Matches(code);
```

Comment: It is not my "informations". As the [regex tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) states, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool. Also, never use `(?:.|[\r\n])*?` unless you do not care about performance.  In C#, use `.*?` and compile the regex with `RegexOptions.Singleline`. In C#, `Regex.Split` will also add captures to the resulting array, it might not be that convenient as in PHP.

Comment: An idea: since you want to tokenize a string, use the regex in `Regex.Matches`, collect the indices where each match starts and ends, and then build the array of string between those indices.